# Remove duplicate hash from perl array

Tags: perl

I have the perl array as below

```
my @arr = ({
  CONTEXTID => 1230,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 163
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 77
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 779
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 141
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 1230,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 163
})
```

I want to remove the duplicate hashes from the array , The output should be like this:

```
({
  CONTEXTID => 1230,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 163
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 77
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 779
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 141
}
)
```

The duplicate will be identified only when all the keys of hash are matching else its not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of the stackoverflow answer I got this solution which works for me , I don't remember the original post thought.

```
 my %seen;
 my @array;
 @array =  grep { my $e = $_; my $key = join '___', map { $e->{$_}; } sort keys %$_;!$seen{$key}++ } @array;
```

put your array of href inside the array variable and returned array will be having unique hash values.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a common idiom for removing duplicates:

```
my %seen;    
my @unique = grep !$seen{$_}++, @strings;
```

That use a string comparisons to determine if two items are identical or not. That will not do in our case (as that would effectively compare the addresses of the hashes, finding them all unique).

But we can easily generalize the above as follows:

```
my %seen;    
my @unique = grep !$seen{key($_)}++, @items;
```

All we need now is a function `key` that produces a string such that the following conditions are true:

- `key($a) ne key($b)` if `$a` is considered to be different than `$b`.
- `key($a) eq key($b)` if `$a` is considered to be the same as `$b`.

In this case, we could use the following:

```
use feature qw( state );

use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );

sub key {
   state $encoder = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->canonical;
   return $encoder->encode($_[0]);
}
```

Comment: An alternative form of the algorithm: `use List::UtilsBy 'uniq_by'; my @unique = uniq_by { key($_) } @items;`

Comment: A lot of work just to replace something with which one should be familiar, but it is more self-documenting.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the answer, But my existing code based doesn't allow to introduce the perl module Cpanel::JSON::XS

Comment: The concept still applies whether you use that module or not. Adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that following piece satisfies your requirements

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @result;
my %seen;

my @arr = ({
  CONTEXTID => 1230,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 163
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 77
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 779
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 8824,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 141
}, {
  CONTEXTID => 1230,
  NAME => 'test8824',
  PROVIDERID => 163
});

foreach my $el ( @arr ) {
    my $k = join('|', @$el{qw/CONTEXTID NAME PROVIDERID/ });
    push @result, $el unless $seen{$k};
    $seen{$k} = 1;
}

print Dumper(\@result);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'PROVIDERID' => 163,
            'CONTEXTID' => 1230,
            'NAME' => 'test8824'
          },
          {
            'NAME' => 'test8824',
            'CONTEXTID' => 8824,
            'PROVIDERID' => 77
          },
          {
            'CONTEXTID' => 8824,
            'PROVIDERID' => 779,
            'NAME' => 'test8824'
          },
          {
            'NAME' => 'test8824',
            'CONTEXTID' => 8824,
            'PROVIDERID' => 141
          }
        ];
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that the every record has the same three keys, but that's probably ok.